# I can't use setText() in onClick()

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4P15.png)I'm trying to work with setText but this doesn't work when it goes in to  onClick. In code, It's fine in onCreate not onClick but when setText in onClick (- in onCreate) It show red color when tell me that cannot resolve this function

&it>

```
ToggleButton gpsToggleButton;
TextView  gpsTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //permission area
    //get user permission using of gps
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        gpsuserPermission();
    }

    gpsToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton_gps);
    gpsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_gps);
    gpsTextView.setText("why it doesn't work?");
    final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    gpsToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View gpsTextView) {

            try{
                if(gpsToggleButton.isChecked()){
                    gpsTextView.setText();/// THIS PART CAUSE ERROR[
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, locationListener);
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 10, locationListener);
                    gpsTextView.setText();/// THIS PART CAUSE ERROR[enter image description here][1]
                }

            }catch (SecurityException ex){
                    gpsTextView.setTextAlignment());
            }
        }

    });




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ((ToggleButton)gpsTextView).setText("");
```

or

```
 gpsToggleButton.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the header:

```
public void onClick(View gpsTextView)
```

with:

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

it is the toggle button that is clicked not the `TextView`  
in your current code inside the `onClick()` method `gpsTextView` is considered a different view, the view that was clicked meaning the toggle button not the actual `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you really need to combine the solutions provide by **@ItzikSamara**  and **@mTak**.

You have defined a class variable "gpsTextView"  to point to your `TextView` object that you wish to reference. But, in the `onClick()` method you have overwritten this variable locally by using the same variable name as the parameter name:
`public void onClick(View gpsTextView)` --> `public void onClick(View v)`. 
**as mTak suggested**.

By changing the parameter name to something else (in this case "v"), you will have access to the class variable "gpsTextView" and you can set the text value using the `setText()` method. But, you should actually set the text to something--like an empty string --> `gpsTextView.setText("")` **as ItzikSamara  suggested**.

Change your code to this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try{
        if(gpsToggleButton.isChecked()){
            gpsTextView.setText("");
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, locationListener);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 10, locationListener);
            //gpsTextView.setText(); -- No need to do this twice!
        }
    }catch (SecurityException ex){
        Log.e("MyActivity", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```